# regex for mobile number validation in java

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to have phone number in working combination of '0' followed by 10 digit mobile number (or) 0091 folllowed by 10 digit mobile number (or) +91 followed by 10 digit number.

1) 0 followed and +91 folowed numbers are working with following regex i also want 0091 followed number to be worked, my regex is:

```
"^([0]|(?:[0][0]|\\+)(91))([7-9]{1})([0-9]{9})$";
```

Could you suggest me working a regex.

Comment: no i havent tried anything

Comment: did you try to play around with a regexp testing site such as: http://regexpal.com/ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact regex you seem to be going for (based on what you've tried so far) is:

```
^(?:0091|\\+91|0)[7-9][0-9]{9}$
```

- Begins with 0, +91 or 0091
- Followed by a 7-9
- Followed by exactly 9 numbers
- No capture groups
- Must match entire input

[Working example on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37d3i)

**As a general tip**, to have worked this out yourself I'd advise using a site like [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) or [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com)

Set it to multi-line mode (so that `^` and `$` match at the end of each line) then add `0091`, `+91` and `0` into the input box on separate lines - so you have [something like this](http://regexr.com?37d3l).

Then try to make a regex that matches just that part, in your case you needed something like

```
^0091|\+91|0$
```

**Note:** on RegExr you don't have to escape backslashes (so when you use the regex in java you need to go through escaping them).

Answer (score 2):

Guess this regex would work:

```
^((0091)|(\+91)|(0))([7-9]{1})([0-9]{9})$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Android, you could use this method:
`PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber("+91.......)`

Or try to do something like that if you really want to use regex:

```
if (match("^0[0-9]{9}") || match("^+91[0-9]{10}") || match("^0091[0-9]{9}"))
```

Comment: thank u for good logic and i gave upvote

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code (test.matches(..) ist the important part):

```
    String test = "00911234567891";
    System.out.println(test.matches("(0091|0|\\+91)[7-9][0-9]{9}"));
```

Comment: why / what exactly? I tried it and it returned true for 0091 + number, 0 + number and +91 + number.

Comment: ah I see now the problem. You distinguish between mobile and normal number. How is a mobile number identified?

Comment: sorry mate its working i upvoted ur answer

Comment: @ManuelM. - the new regex is significantly worse than the previous one (which looked about right)

Comment: restored the correct version.

Answer (score -1):

This regex should work.

You can use `^([0]|\+91)?\d{10}` as starts with `0` or `+91` and `10` digits after that.

Comment: As far as I can tell, OP doesn't want to match 2 (and in your regex exactly 2) comma separated numbers.

Comment: sorry i already have 0 and +91 working ,i need 0091 to get worked in same regex